# WSO2 not able to receive data from Kafka Topic

Tags: apache-kafka, wso2, wso2-streaming-integrator

I have a **WSO2 Stream Processor** code running where i have 6 different Kafka topics as @source and respectively 6 Mysql Database connection.
I am able to receive data in 5 topics but one, but the same topic is working if i run the code individually. Example,

Topic List:
**Topic1,Topic2,Topic3,Topic4,Topic5,Topic6**
**Topic 2-6 can get data.**

**But if i execute Topic 1 as a standalone program in WSO2, its able to get data but not when executed with all other topics as one program.**

I am not able to figure out any probable cause for this, any inputs and ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue, it was because My local system wasn't able to handle streaming data load and it was getting out of memory though no error was displayed. If i reduce the data volume it's working fine.